how to make sqlite database of a custom made object so don't have to declare every field in database class in android studio?
how can we make sqlite database using a custom object that has different type of declared datatype init so that we don't have to declare every single filed in the database class.
i am making an app that manages employee sqlite database so i had made an custom object (model class)that has declared every filed that i need to manage in different datatypes. so now want to know that how can we insert this whole custom object into database so that i don't have to declare every field in database.

You could use the BLOB data type as described at SQLite - CREATE TABLE. This allows any set of bytes to be stored together.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This code works for me in kotlin language.
class FavouriteDataBaseHelper(context: Context?) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
    private val gson = Gson()

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        val createTableQuery =
            "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_WALLPAPER ($COLUMN_KEY INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $COLUMN_WALLPAPER_INFO TEXT)"
        db.execSQL(createTableQuery)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_WALLPAPER")
        onCreate(db)
    }

    fun insertWallpaper(data: WallpaperRoot): WallpaperRoot? {
        val db = writableDatabase
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(COLUMN_WALLPAPER_INFO, serializeWallpaperRoot(data))
        }

        val result = db.insert(TABLE_WALLPAPER, null, contentValues)

        return if (result != -1L) {
            val insertedId = getLastInsertedId(db)
            data.id = insertedId
            Log.d(TAG, "insertData: insertedId = $insertedId")
            updateWallpaper(data)
            data
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    private fun getLastInsertedId(db: SQLiteDatabase): Int {
        var id = -1
        db.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid()", null).use { cursor ->
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                id = cursor.getInt(0)
            }
        }
        return id
    }

    fun updateWallpaper(data: WallpaperRoot): Boolean {
        Log.d(TAG, "updateWallpaper: data.toString() = ${data.toString()}")
        val db = writableDatabase
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(COLUMN_WALLPAPER_INFO, serializeWallpaperRoot(data))
        }

        val rowsAffected = db.update(
            TABLE_WALLPAPER, contentValues, "$COLUMN_KEY = ?", arrayOf(data.id.toString())
        )
        return rowsAffected > 0
    }

    fun getAllWallpaperList(): List<WallpaperRoot> {
        val memoList = mutableListOf<WallpaperRoot>()
        val db = readableDatabase
        db.query(TABLE_WALLPAPER, null, null, null, null, null, null).use { cursor ->
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    val memoInfoString =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_WALLPAPER_INFO))
                    val memoInfo = deserializeWallpaperRoot(memoInfoString)
                    memoList.add(memoInfo)
                } while (cursor.moveToNext())
            }
        }
        db.close()
        return memoList
    }

    fun searchWallpaperByName(query: String): List<WallpaperRoot> {
        val searchResults = mutableListOf<WallpaperRoot>()
        val db = readableDatabase

        db.query(TABLE_WALLPAPER, null, null, null, null, null, null).use { cursor ->
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    val wallpaperInfoString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_WALLPAPER_INFO))
                    val wallpaper = deserializeWallpaperRoot(wallpaperInfoString)

                    if (wallpaper.name?.contains(query, ignoreCase = true) == true) {
                        searchResults.add(wallpaper)
                    }
                } while (cursor.moveToNext())
            }
        }
        db.close()
        return searchResults
    }

    fun deleteWallpaper(id: Int): Boolean {
        val db = writableDatabase

        // Delete the row with the specified id
        val rowsAffected = db.delete(
            TABLE_WALLPAPER, "$COLUMN_KEY = ?", arrayOf(id.toString())
        )

        db.close()
        return rowsAffected > 0 // Return true if deletion was successful
    }


    private fun serializeWallpaperRoot(eventInfo: WallpaperRoot): String {
        return gson.toJson(eventInfo)
    }

    private fun deserializeWallpaperRoot(eventInfoString: String): WallpaperRoot {
        return gson.fromJson(eventInfoString, WallpaperRoot::class.java)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "wallpaper.db"
        private const val TAG = "FavouriteDataBaseHelper"
        private const val TABLE_WALLPAPER = "wallpaper"
        private const val COLUMN_KEY = "id"
        private const val COLUMN_WALLPAPER_INFO = "wallpaper_info"
    }
}

i am using WallpaperRoot as custom object to insert into database.

i have a way to make custom object to insert to sqlite database.
here's my database class
   public class MemoDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "memo.db";
    private static final String TAG = "MemoDataBaseHelper";
    private static final String TABLE_MEMO = "memo";
    private static final String COLUMN_KEY = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_MEMO_INFO = "memo_info";
    private Gson gson;

    public MemoDataBaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        gson = new Gson();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String createTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEMO + " (" +
                COLUMN_KEY + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_MEMO_INFO + " TEXT)";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(createTableQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEMO);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public boolean insertMemo(MemoRoot data) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_MEMO_INFO, serializeMemoRoot(data));

        // Insert data into the database
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_MEMO, null, contentValues);

        // Check if insertion was successful
        if (result != -1) {
            // Get the id of the inserted row
            int insertedId = getLastInsertedId(db);
            // Update the GoalRoot object with the inserted id
            data.id = insertedId;
            Log.d(TAG, "insertData: insertedId = " + insertedId);
            // Update the row with the id
            updateMemo(data);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Method to get the last inserted id
    private int getLastInsertedId(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid()", null);
        int id = -1;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            id = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return id;
    }

    public boolean updateMemo(MemoRoot data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "updateMemo: data.toString() = " + data.toString());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_MEMO_INFO, serializeMemoRoot(data));
        // Update the row with the specified id
        int rowsAffected = db.update(TABLE_MEMO, contentValues, COLUMN_KEY + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(data.id)});
        return rowsAffected > 0;
    }

    public List<MemoRoot> getAllMemoList() {
        List<MemoRoot> goalList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MEMO, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String eventInfoString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_MEMO_INFO));
                MemoRoot eventInfo = deserializeMemoRoot(eventInfoString);
                goalList.add(eventInfo);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return goalList;
    }
    public List<MemoRoot> searchMemo(String query) {
        List<MemoRoot> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // Define the search query
        String selection = COLUMN_MEMO_INFO + " LIKE ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {"%" + query + "%"};

        // Perform the query
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MEMO, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        // Iterate through the results and add them to the searchResults list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String memoInfoString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_MEMO_INFO));
                MemoRoot memo = deserializeMemoRoot(memoInfoString);
                searchResults.add(memo);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return searchResults;
    }

    public boolean deleteMemo(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete the row with the specified id
        int rowsAffected = db.delete(TABLE_MEMO, COLUMN_KEY + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        return rowsAffected > 0;
    }

    private String serializeMemoRoot(MemoRoot eventInfo) {
        return gson.toJson(eventInfo);
    }

    private MemoRoot deserializeMemoRoot(String eventInfoString) {
        return gson.fromJson(eventInfoString, MemoRoot.class);
    }}    

in this class i am using MemoRoot as custom object for inserting data into database. you can modify this class as per requirements.
